# javascript reload addEventListner when creating dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm building a project where on a form there is multiple camera buttons. Example one to take photos of the environment and another to take photos of the users etc. I'm using vanilla javascript. This is a responsive website with html and css.

When the data capture user presses the camera button I use

> input accept='image/*' onclick=\"assignVar('inp_img6','file-upload6')\"
>   capture='camera'

I then use the values to resize images and create base64 values to update hidden input fields to submit when the user uploads.

So with static buttons this works great. My problem comes when I want to create buttons dynamically or with a  + so the user can add more photos.

I use an addEventListner to see if the file input has changed and then run my function to resize photos and add the base64 to the hidden input.

When I then create the + button to add more fields the addEventListner is not working.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to make a work around? I'm a javascript beginner and tried searching without any luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) *"I use an addEventListner...the addEventListner is not working."* We can't help you with code we can't see. Please add a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Attach the event to the newly-created element, or delegate it to the nearest common ancestor element.

Comment: Thanks not sure what this means.. I use document.getElementById('id_upload0').addEventListener('change', fileChange, false); so instead of using document.getElementById do you suggest to make a div and then check on the div?

Comment: No, use the newly-created element you created by cloning. Notice, that `id`s within the document must be unique. If you just showed your code ...